# Min, Max, Avg Filters in opencv2.4.13

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any built-in function to apply min, max and Avg filters to an image in opencv2.4.13 ?
I'm using c++ .

Comment: Average filter is `boxFilter`. Min and Max filters are not present in OpenCV. However you can find an implementation of a min filter [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33258685/5008845). Max filter will be very similar

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your help , you are very welcome.

Comment: @Miki Would [`erode`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) and [`dilate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) not work as min and max filters?

Comment: @beaker could work (for binary images only?)

Comment: @Micka The docs say that they work for multichannel images, but I've only used them on grayscale.

Comment: @beaker probably yes. I never thought of them in these terms ;D

Comment: I'm going to apply these filters to grayscale images ,can I use erode and dilate concretely ? thanks @beaker for your notice.

Comment: @محمودعبدالكريم I've posted an answer with a sample program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Miki mentioned in the comments, [`boxfilter`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#boxfilter) is a mean filter. Just set the kernel size you want and leave `normalize=true` (the default).

The functions [`erode`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=erode#erode) and [`dilate`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#dilate) are min and max filters, respectively. You can create the kernel using [`createMorphologyFilter`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=dilate#createmorphologyfilter), create your own, or use the default 3x3 as I've done. The borders are set by default to `+inf` for `erode` and `-inf` for `dilate` so they do not contribute to the result.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char image_data[25] = {1, 3, 8, 8, 4, 
                           4, 2, 7, 9, 9, 
                           1, 5, 0, 5, 9, 
                           3, 7, 5, 2, 1, 
                           0, 4, 7, 9, 4};
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(5, 5, CV_8U, image_data);
    std::cout << "image = " << std::endl << image << std::endl;

    cv::Mat avgImage;
    // Perform mean filtering on image using boxfilter
    cv::boxFilter(image, avgImage, -1, cv::Size(3,3));
    std::cout << "avgImage = " << std::endl << avgImage << std::endl;

    cv::Mat kernel;   // Use the default structuring element (kernel) for erode and dilate

    cv::Mat minImage;
    // Perform min filtering on image using erode
    cv::erode(image, minImage, kernel);
    std::cout << "minImage = " << std::endl << minImage << std::endl;

    cv::Mat maxImage;
    // Perform max filtering on image using dilate
    cv::dilate(image, maxImage, kernel);
    std::cout << "maxImage = " << std::endl << maxImage << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results:

```
image = 
[  1,   3,   8,   8,   4;
   4,   2,   7,   9,   9;
   1,   5,   0,   5,   9;
   3,   7,   5,   2,   1;
   0,   4,   7,   9,   4]
avgImage = 
[  3,   4,   6,   8,   8;
   3,   3,   5,   7,   7;
   4,   4,   5,   5,   6;
   4,   4,   5,   5,   5;
   5,   5,   5,   4,   4]
minImage = 
[  1,   1,   2,   4,   4;
   1,   0,   0,   0,   4;
   1,   0,   0,   0,   1;
   0,   0,   0,   0,   1;
   0,   0,   2,   1,   1]
maxImage = 
[  4,   8,   9,   9,   9;
   5,   8,   9,   9,   9;
   7,   7,   9,   9,   9;
   7,   7,   9,   9,   9;
   7,   7,   9,   9,   9]
```

Comment: No built in way of getting a weighted min/max?

Comment: @curator23 Not that I'm aware of.